# Selecting time in calender control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm using the calendar control but need to be able to select a time along with the date.

Can someone recommend a control which provides both date and time functionality?

thanks

Comment: calender control is used to select dates, i don't think its possible to select time with it.

Comment: but is there any other control in asp.net control toolkit which enable this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET DateTime Picker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469280/asp-net-datetime-picker)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use two calendar controls - one for date and one for time.

[image]

Comment: How exactly would the second calendar control be used for time?

Comment: That put it over the +1 line for me :)