# Calender control with date and time?

Tags: asp.net

Can it possible to show time in Ajax Calender Control in asp.net ?I have a `text-box` which populating calender control but i want to show the calender control should display both date and time.Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Try using .... [Jquery Date time picker](http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/)

Comment: http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Comment: http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two calendar controls - one for date and one for time.

[image]

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6496868/3030434)

**Or**

You can with the third party Control - **[Check it Out](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/)**

[Check this too](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213311/Time-Picker-Ajax-Extender-Control).!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date and time picker`

```
<ASP:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate"></ASP:TextBox>

<obout:Calendar runat="server"
                         ShowTimeSelector="true" 
                         DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                         DatePickerMode="true"
                         TextBoxId="txtDate">
</obout:Calendar>
```

[ASP.NET Calendar - Date and time picker](https://www.obout.com/calendar/calendar_datetimepicker.aspx)